# Verifying a certificate against a CRL via OpenSSL: Unable to get certificate CRL

Tags: certificate, openssl, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I am having a problem about verifying a certificate against the CRL that was created by the same CA that created the certificate.

I have created my own certificate authority (CA) and an intermediate CA. By using this intermediate CA, I created several certificates and revoked some of them. I updated the certificate revocation list (CRL) after I revoked them. Then, I appended the CRL to the chain certificate (concatenation of root CA's and intermediate CA's certificates). I wanted to use this file to check if a certificate is revoked or not. The C code I am running returns as expected for revoked certificates while it displays an unexpected message for valid certificates: unable to get certificate CRL. In addition, it returns expected results when I removed CRL checks. What can be the reason for this?

The code that I am running is given below.

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>

int main() {

  const char ca_bundlestr[] = "./ca-chain.crl.pem";//"./ca-chain.cert.pem";//"./ca-chain.crl.pem";
  const char cert_filestr[] = "./RasPi3B-10.1.1.10.crt.pem";//"./ToBeRevoked3.crt.pem";

  BIO              *certbio = NULL;
  BIO               *outbio = NULL;
  X509          *error_cert = NULL;
  X509                *cert = NULL;
  X509_NAME    *certsubject = NULL;
  X509_STORE         *store = NULL;
  X509_STORE_CTX  *vrfy_ctx = NULL;
  int ret;

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * These function calls initialize openssl for correct work.  *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  ERR_load_BIO_strings();
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();

  X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new();

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Create the Input/Output BIO's.                             *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  certbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  outbio  = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Initialize the global certificate validation store object. *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if (!(store=X509_STORE_new()))
     BIO_printf(outbio, "Error creating X509_STORE_CTX object\n");

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Create the context structure for the validation operation. *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  vrfy_ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Load the certificate and cacert chain from file (PEM).     *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  ret = BIO_read_filename(certbio, cert_filestr);
  if (! (cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(certbio, NULL, 0, NULL))) {
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error loading cert into memory\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  ret = X509_STORE_load_locations(store, ca_bundlestr, NULL);
  if (ret != 1)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error loading CA cert or chain file\n");

  X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK|X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL);
  //X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_depth(param, 1);
  //X509_STORE_CTX_set0_param(vrfy_ctx, param);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Initialize the ctx structure for a verification operation: *
   * Set the trusted cert store, the unvalidated cert, and any  *
   * potential certs that could be needed (here we set it NULL) *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  X509_STORE_CTX_init(vrfy_ctx, store, cert, NULL);

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Check the complete cert chain can be build and validated.  *
   * Returns 1 on success, 0 on verification failures, and -1   *
   * for trouble with the ctx object (i.e. missing certificate) *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  ret = X509_verify_cert(vrfy_ctx);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Verification return code: %d\n", ret);

  if(ret == 0 || ret == 1)
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Verification result text: %s\n",
             X509_verify_cert_error_string(vrfy_ctx->error));

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * The error handling below shows how to get failure details  *
   * from the offending certificate.                            *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  if(ret == 0) {
    /*  get the offending certificate causing the failure */
    error_cert  = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(vrfy_ctx);
    certsubject = X509_NAME_new();
    certsubject = X509_get_subject_name(error_cert);
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Verification failed cert:\n");
    X509_NAME_print_ex(outbio, certsubject, 0, XN_FLAG_MULTILINE);
    BIO_printf(outbio, "\n");
  }

  /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
   * Free up all structures                                     *
   * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
  X509_STORE_CTX_free(vrfy_ctx);
  X509_STORE_free(store);
  X509_free(cert);
  BIO_free_all(certbio);
  BIO_free_all(outbio);
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an intermediate CA, you need to provide both, the CRL of the root CA and the CRL of the intermediate CA (the full chain). You can do this by simply concatenating the CRLs.